# Python File reading and writing

Tags: python

I'm currently coding a program that is supposed to:

1)  Open a file which has names along with grades on each line
(I have successfully done this and put the contents of each line into an array).

2)  Evaluate the data and find the max, min, and average.

I am stuck in the second part because if I try to use the max or min function pertaining to the array, I have an error code that pops up, since the values in the array are technically a string.

So my question is how do I only get the value of the numbers? Would a parallel list be more useful and if so how would I implement that?

Here's my code so far:

```
def getGrades(filename):

    try:
        gradeArray = []
        with open("Grades.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                gradeArray.append(line.find())
    except:
        print("Could not open", filename)
    return(gradeArray)
```

Comment: Do not use bare-except clauses. Always try to catch the most specific errors you can.

Comment: Use `int()` or `float()` to convert to numeric values?

Comment: the reason i can't just do Int() is because the lines of text look like this.
Larry Smith: 80 so the string in front gets in the way

Comment: @JoshLee well, then you'll need to parse those lines, no? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have this set up in another function
line.find(": ") but it definitely isn't working unless I'm using it incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Optimize as needed:

```
minValue = 0
maxValue = 0
total = 0
first = int(gradeArray[0])
total = first
for i in range(1, len(gradeArray)):
    minValue = min(first, int(gradeArray[i]))
    maxValue = max(first, int(gradeArray[i]))
    total = total + int(gradeArray[i])
average = total / len(gradeArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do have one issue and that is that the values in the array look something like this:
Larry Smith: 80

so I only need the numeric value at the end and I'm unsure of how to do that

Comment: ```gradeArray.append(line.split(':')[1])```